# Replacing text in Word doc with text from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, replace, ms-word

I am looking to create a via script in excel that will replace a text holder in a word doc with some text from excel.

I can get the via script to open the word doc, and then save the doc under a new name. however it will not execute the replace text part :(

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        wdApp.Visible = False
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("temp.docx")

    With wdDoc.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "<<name>>"
        With .Replacement
            .ClearFormatting
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Text = "John Smith"
        End With
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

    wdDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:=("temp2.docx")

    Set wdApp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have tried doing a search in here but can't see where I am going wrong :(

currently it opens the word doc and saves it under a new name but does not replace the find and replace the text. Can anyone see where I have gone wrong and show me how to get it right?

Comment: What do you mean by text holder? do you have word "<<name>>" in word document?

Comment: yes, should really of called it a place holder. It is just to make it easier to find where to replace with the required text. The plan is to have a form that can be opened and edited as a word doc or filled in by an excel form.

Comment: Look up the concept of BOOKMARK in Word. You use that without Find/Replace. As to what you have: you're sure you typed <<name>> and that this is not a merge field? If yes, you need a Word.Range object set to wdDoc.Content and use Find with that. In addition, Set wdApp = Nothing must follow Set wdDoc = Nothing. And if you leave wdApp not visible you MUST Quit it, otherwise you're levaing it open in memory, whic is a BAD IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

When I set up a test for your problem description in Word, by typing <<name>> I see that Word replaces the two angled brackets with special symbols. And it offers the possibility to undo the AutoCorrect causing this.

Querying ASC(Selection.Text) on them gives Chr(171) and Chr(187), which are also double-angled bracket symbols, but using them in Find does not work. Querying AscW() reveals the two symbols are Unicode 8810 and 8811, so they need to be searched differently.

Assuming that's the issue in your case, the following works:

```
With wdDoc.content.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = ChrW(8810) & "name" & ChrW(8811) '"<<name>>"
    With .Replacement
        .ClearFormatting
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Text = "John Smith"
    End With
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

Further to your code - it has other, potentially grave problems (memory leak):

If you do this: `wdApp.Visible = False` then you need to be absolutely certain to remove Word from memory:

```
wdDoc.Close
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing
```

Unlike Excel, Word won't quit automatically when its object goes out of scope (macro ends). It will stay open, which you can see in the Task Manager.

In addition, you need to release the objects in the reverse order in which they were instantiated - wdDoc *before* wdApp.

Comment: I gave this a try but it did not work. I then tried changing the placeholder text to just name and searching for that, ad again that did not work.

I have however implemented the close and quit to prevent memory loss. I have also looked into the Bookmarker and have managed to get that to work so will probably use that in my project.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @EuanLivingstone Well, if it didn't work then there's something (else) weird in your document - something not evident in your problem description. FIND does work in Word. Is the text you're searching actually formatted with BOLD? This Find is specific for Bold since you have that in the code you gave us. You might test that in order to prove to yourself the FIND works (and that my contribution does answer your question, as it stands).

Answer (score 0):

Setup some DocVariables in your Word doc and run the code below, from within Excel.

```
Sub PushToWord()

Dim objWord As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim bkmk As Word.Bookmark
sWdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , , , False)
Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open(sWdFileName)
'On Error Resume Next

objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("BrokerFirstName").Value = Range("BrokerFirstName").Value
objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("BrokerLastName").Value = Range("BrokerLastName").Value
objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("Ryan").Value = Range("Ryan").Value


objWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

'On Error Resume Next
objWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```

You can use essentially the same process by setting up Bookmarks in Word, and pushing data from fields in Excel to fields (Bookmarks) in Word.

```
Sub PushToWord()

Dim objWord As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim bkmk As Word.Bookmark
sWdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , , , False)
Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open(sWdFileName)
On Error Resume Next

    ActiveDocument.Variables("BrokerFirstName").Value = Range("B1").Value
    ActiveDocument.Variables("BrokerLastName").Value = Range("B2").Value
    ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

On Error Resume Next
objWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: ```sWdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , , , False)```
Can you please explain what is this line doing in here??
And what ```sWdFileName``` stands for??

Answer (score -3):

The famouse hope - to have one button for all live cases with caption: "Make it OK!"

Do divide the task on parts:
- Get "... text from excel ..."
- "replace text in word doc ..." with text getted from Excel on previouse step

Do it by two separate procedures for each of tasks,
called from the third procedure united them.

.